# Что значит "ArrayList - динамический массив"?

Tags: list, динамические-массивы

Гуглил, и увидел что `List` - это динамический массив.

И вообще я часто встречал слова динамический и статический в программировании. Что же это значит?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Динамический означает, что память под элементы контейнера выделяется во время выполнения программы по мере необходимости. А статический означает, что размер выделяемый памяти известен до загрузки программы на выполнение.

Например, список может быть реализован с помощью массива, размер которого задается фиксированным значением, и не меняется во время выполнения программы. А можно реализовать список таким образом, что при вставке нового элемента в список для него выделяется память в момент вставки этого элемента.

Answer (score 4):

В отрыве от контекста эти термины нельзя рассматривать.  Применительно к массивам - статический массив это выделенный участок памяти для хранения данных фиксированного размера, в статический массив нельзя добавлять новые элементы; динамический массив это структура данных  организованная таким образом, чтобы в любой момент в масив можно было добавить новый элемент или удалить произвольный.

Термины статический и динамический могут иметь и другие значения. Например, динамическая и статическая линковка. При динамической линковке часть кода компилируется в библиотечный файл (dll) и подключается к приложению во время выполнения. При статической линковке весь код компилируется непосредственно в  исполнимый файл

Comment: Я почему-то не могу понять чем отличается статическая переменные(свойства) и методы от обычных.

Comment: @антонсорокин, дайте ссылку на описание, которое вы прочитали, но не поняли.

Comment: я прочитал несклько статей, но автор попросил пример

Answer (score 3):

Например, мы написали какую-то программку, которая обрабатывает массив. При написании данной программы необходимо было объявить массив, то есть задать ему фиксированный размер (к примеру, от 0 до 100 элементов). Тогда данная программа будет не универсальной, ведь может обрабатывать массив размером не более 100 элементов. А если нам понадобятся всего 20 элементов, но в памяти выделится место под 100 элементов, ведь объявление массива было статическим.